# How to call Android activity from a java servlet?

Tags: java, android, sql-server, servlets

I am working on an android application, which is sends and gets data from MS SQL server via java servlets.

I need to update the UI of the application when Database has been updated.
I was thinking of implementing a looper class which will call a servlet via HTTP asyncTask, and call the servlet every few minutes. But it will be lots of work for the application and will slow down and also the UI needs to be updated as soon as the database has been updated.

Is there any way I can invoke the android application, from the servlet as soon as the Database has been updated? I cannot wait for the android application to make a call to servlet and check if database has been updated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the first time I am writing a question on SO, please  pardon my mistakes and suggest me how to improve.

Big thanks,
Ashley

Comment: Study [Push Notifications](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/), while this tutorial is in Php, same thing you can develop in Servlet or .net

Comment: @Kedarnath Thank you for your reply, I ll read through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A java servlet is stateless.  This means that the connection is not maintained.  The java servlet knows nothing of your application and cannot communicate directly with it.

If you must maintain the servlet setup then you can use Google Cloud Messaging to push the update to the user's phone.  This is not exactly instantaneous though and there is a delay.

The thing that would work best for you is to change your java servlet into a java application that has a socket.  You would then communicate with your java application via the socket and keep it open in a background thread.  This thread will hold a callback to your activity which can populate it when a response is sent back over the thread to say data has been received.